# Увеличить размер базы данных для тестирования

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, sql-server

У меня есть база данных из 100 марок машин. Мне нужно увеличить размер базы в 1000 раз, то есть до 100000 марок. Это нужно для тестирования и поэтому эти 100 марок можно просто повторить 1000 раз. Использую "java" и "SQL Server 2005".

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: проблема не очевидна

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into Marks(a,b,c)
select A.a,A.b,A.c
  from Marks A, Marks B
```

Если в таблице 100 записей, то такой запрос сделает уже 100*100 т.е. 10000 записей. Добавьте в from еще табличку или подзапрос, который выдает 10 записей и получите свои 100k. К полям можно добавлять значения например `row_number()` или `rand()` что бы разнообразить значения.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE( randnum float )
DECLARE @cnt INT; SET @cnt = 0
WHILE @cnt <=1000
BEGIN
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT RAND( (DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) * 100000 )
+ (DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) * 1000 )
+ DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()) )
END
SELECT randnum, COUNT(*)
FROM @t
GROUP BY randnum
```

отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6371562/6679190

Точно также, при желании, можно селектить не рандомные значения, а таблицу со 100 марками.

Answer (score 0):

While 1=1

```
INSERT INTO 'your table'
VALUES (NEW ID(), 
        NEW ID(), 
        NEW ID(), 
        DatePart(millisecond,GetDate())
```